Minimal number of way to partition a complete graph to form bipartite spanning subgraph
More specifically, suppose $K_n = (V,E)$, let k be the number of ways to partition $E$ into $E1, E2, E3,...,E_k$ such that each $G=(V,E_i)$ is a spanning subgraph of $K_n$ and bipartite, what is the minimal number of k for each n?
I think for $K_3$, $k = 2$. For $K_4, k = 2$, for $K_5, k = 3$, but I fail to derive a formal argument for the patterns here. Would someone gives me some direction to think? Thanks!
Edit: the question is different from Covering a complete graph with as few complete bipartite subgraphs as possible because biclique covering number $()$ of a graph  is the the smallest number of bicliques (complete bipartite subgraphs) of   such that every edge of  belongs to at least one of these bicliques. Yet the bipartite subgraph does not have to be complete for my question.

The two questions really are equivalent. If you have a partition of $K_n$ into bipartite subgraphs, you can replace each bipartite subgraph by the complete bipartite graph between its parts, and then you get a biclique cover. Going the other way, if you have a biclique cover, you can remove each edge from all but one of the subgraphs covering it, and get the partition in this question.

(The two problems stop being equivalent if we generalize $K_n$ to arbitrary graphs, in which case the biclique covering problem is more restrictive.)
